# MySQL: Join a table with multiple line of data

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 tables. The first one contain some global information, and the second contain a list of images.

When I execute this request:

```
SELECT table1.title, table1.description, table2.image LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.table1_id = table1.table1_id
```

Tables structure:

TABLE1

```
| table1_id | title | description |
| 1 | title1 | description1 |
| 2 | title2 | description2 |
| 3 | title3 | description3 |
```

TABLE2

```
| id | table1_id | image |
| 1 | 1 | img/img1.png |
| 2 | 1 | img/img2.png |
| 3 | 1 | img/img3.png |
| 4 | 2 | img/img4.png |
| 5 | 2 | img/img5.png |
| 6 | 3 | img/img6.png |
```

I got something like that:

```
<?php
array(
    array('title' => 'title1', 'description' => 'description1', 'image' => 'img/img1.png'),
    array('title' => 'title1', 'description' => 'description1', 'image' => 'img/img2.png'),
    array('title' => 'title1', 'description' => 'description1', 'image' => 'img/img3.png'),
    array('title' => 'title2', 'description' => 'description2', 'image' => 'img/img4.png'),
    array('title' => 'title2', 'description' => 'description2', 'image' => 'img/img5.png'),
    array('title' => 'title3', 'description' => 'description3', 'image' => 'img/img6.png')
);
?>
```

The problem with this kind of structure is duplicated title, description.
I'd like to get something like that:

```
<?php
array(
    array('title' => 'title1', 'description' => 'description1', 'image' => 
        array('img/img1.png', 'img/img2.png', 'img/img3.png')
    ),
    array('title' => 'title2', 'description' => 'description2', 'image' => 
        array('img/img1.png', 'img/img2.png')
    ),
    array('title' => 'title3', 'description' => 'description3', 'image' => 
        array('img/img6.png')
    )
);
?>
```

My questions are:

- Is it possible to get this kind of structure of data just with a SQL request (No PHP manipulation..)
- If not, what kind of PHP manipulation I have to do to transform my first array to my second array?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is a little confusing. Maybe if you include your related Database table structures that would help me [and maybe others] understand what the underlying issue is.

Comment: I added table structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `group` clause and `group_concat` function. I'm not sure whether it creates an array in PHP, but it's almost what you want:

```
SELECT table1.title, table1.description, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.image) LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id GROUP BY table1.id
```

You can use `explode` function in PHP to transform the result of `GROUP_CONCAT(table2.image)` to PHP array

See the documentation of [MySQL's group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [PHP's explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) functions.

Comment: @tilix - this is as close as you'll get to what you want. Your PHP output will look like this for each title: `array('title' => 'title1', 'description' => 'description1', 'image' => 'img/img1.png,img/img2.png,img/img3.png')`. You can `explode` the `image` item to get the individual filenames.

Comment: @EdGibbs - I update my answer few seconds ago. Thanks for comment anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a select on all the distinct (Name, Description) tuples.  Then you'll have an array of Name,Descriptions, and a null third element.  Then loop through this array and get all the images for that distinct tuple.  Then take that result and insert it into the third element.

Query get array of name/descriptions:

```
select distinct table1.title, table2.description left join table2 on table2.id = table1.id
```

Query to find all images of the distinct name/description tuples:

```
select table2.image inner join table1 on table1.id = table2.id where table1.name = arr[0] and table1.description = arr[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily build the structure you're after when you iterate over the results, either was you're going to have to manipulate the result-set.

```
<?php
$items = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ( ! isset($items[ $row['title'] ])) {
        $items[ $row['title'] ] = array(
            'title'         => $row['title'],
            'description'   => $row['description'],
            'images'        => array($row['image']),
        );
        continue;
    }
    $items[ $row['title'] ]['images'][] = $row['image'];
}
$items = array_values($items);
```

Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

```
PHP code:

<?php
/*here is your result array*/
$result = array(
    array('title' => 'tile1', 'description' => 'description1', 'image' => 'img/img1.png'),
    array('title' => 'tile1', 'description' => 'description1', 'image' => 'img/img2.png'),
    array('title' => 'tile1', 'description' => 'description1', 'image' => 'img/img3.png'),
    array('title' => 'tile2', 'description' => 'description2', 'image' => 'img/img4.png'),
    array('title' => 'tile2', 'description' => 'description2', 'image' => 'img/img5.png'),
    array('title' => 'tile3', 'description' => 'description3', 'image' => 'img/img6.png')
);

/*creating a new formatted array*/
$newResult = array();
foreach($result as $value){
    $newResult[$value['title']]['title'] = $value['title'];
    $newResult[$value['title']]['description'] = $value['description'];
    $newResult[$value['title']]['image'][] = $value['image'];
}

/*printing new final formatted array*/
print_r($newResult));
?>
```